Optimization of CGAL Delauny Triangulation because is very slow C++
I am trying to make a delauny triangle with a data set of around 400.000 points, I managed to do it and it gives me a time of 19 seconds approximately, but later I want to make a triangulation with 10 million points, 19 seconds is too long for so few points, my question is that you recommend me to assemble the Delauny triangle is much more efficient?
I have read that doing the triangulation in parts is much shorter, but I don't know how to join the resulting meshes.
Any advice on how to optimize or a more efficient way to assemble the delauny triangulation?
// Compares the result of several interpolation methods

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

#include <CGAL/Random.h>
#include <CGAL/squared_distance_2.h>

#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Interpolation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/natural_neighbor_coordinates_2.h>
#include <CGAL/interpolation_functions.h>

#include <CGAL/point_generators_2.h>
#include <CGAL/algorithm.h>
#include <CGAL/Origin.h>

#include <cassert>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT                                         Coord_type;
typedef K::Vector_2                                   Vector;
typedef K::Point_2                                    Point;

typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K>             Delaunay_triangulation;
typedef CGAL::Interpolation_traits_2<K>               Traits;

typedef std::vector< std::pair<Point, Coord_type> >   Coordinate_vector;
typedef std::map<Point, Coord_type, K::Less_xy_2>     Point_value_map;
typedef std::map<Point, Vector, K::Less_xy_2 >       Point_vector_map;


void readExcelCSV(std::vector<Point>& points, std::vector<Point>& pointsInterpolation, Point_value_map& values, Delaunay_triangulation& T) {
    std::ifstream file("datos.csv");
    std::ifstream filePoints("datosforInterpolation.csv");

    if (!file || !filePoints) {
        std::cerr << "Error in Open File." << std::endl;
        return;
    }


    std::string line;

    int cont = 0;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string value;
        std::vector<double> row;
        
        for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
        {
            std::getline(ss, value, ',');
            row.push_back(std::stod(value));
        }
       
        points.push_back(Point(row[0], row[1]));
        T.insert(points[cont]);
        Coord_type value2 = row[2];
        values.insert(std::make_pair(points[cont], value2));
        cont++;
    }
    cont = 0;
    while (std::getline(filePoints, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::string value;
        std::vector<double> row;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
        {
            std::getline(ss, value, ',');
            row.push_back(std::stod(value));
        }

        pointsInterpolation.push_back(Point(row[0], row[1]));
        cont++;
    }

    filePoints.close();
    file.close();
    
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points;
    std::vector<Point> pointsInterpolation;
    Delaunay_triangulation T;

    Point_value_map values;
    Point_vector_map gradients;
    
    std::cout << "Go to read File csv..." << std::endl;
    readExcelCSV(points, pointsInterpolation,values, T);
    std::cout << "Read Excel and build delauny triangulation" << std::endl;
    
    //variables for statistics:
    std::pair<Coord_type, bool> res;
    Coord_type  l_total = Coord_type(0),
       l_value(l_total);
   

    //interpolation + error statistics
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsInterpolation.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "point " << i << std::endl;
        Coord_type x(pointsInterpolation[i].x());
        Coord_type y(pointsInterpolation[i].y());

        
        std::cout << pointsInterpolation[i].x() << " " << pointsInterpolation[i].y()<< std::endl;
        //Coordinate_vector:
        std::vector< std::pair< Point, Coord_type > > coords;
        Coord_type norm =
            CGAL::natural_neighbor_coordinates_2(T, pointsInterpolation[i],
                std::back_inserter(coords)).second;

        assert(norm > 0);
        if (coords.empty()) {
             std::cout << pointsInterpolation[i].x() << " " << pointsInterpolation[i].y() <<" Not valid coords" << std::endl;
             continue;
        }
        //linear interpolant:
        l_value = CGAL::linear_interpolation(coords.begin(), coords.end(),
            norm,
            CGAL::Data_access<Point_value_map>(values));
       
        std::cout << pointsInterpolation[i].x() << " " << pointsInterpolation[i].y() << " " << l_value << std::endl;
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The code I show is an adaptation I made from an example code I found in the official CGAL documentation. I will leave the link below for reference. CGAL 6.0 - 2D and Surface Function Interpolation
I tried reading the csv file, saving it to a vector, closing the file and then building the mesh with that vector but it did not produce significant changes in the mesh build time.

Did you compile in "release" mode? On my machine triangulating 10 million points is 6s.

I followed the steps that are in the official documentation to be able to compile the examples and then on one of the examples (the example that has the link) I started to change the code, I compile it in Release x64 and then I look for the executable that it generates in the Release folder in the path of examples/triangulation.
I want to create a new empty project and import the libraries to work in a clean workspace, but I can't figure out how to do it. Anyway, I am already running it in release, I am using windows - visual studio 2022.

Is it the reading/parsing of the file that is too slow, or the calculations of the triangles afterwards that is too slow?  (Or to put it another way, if you just read the data out of the file but comment out the code that does the Delaunay triangulation, how long does the resulting program take just for that part?)

You should share the data so we can try to reproduce locally.

Please share the input files so that we can try to reproduce and fix if needed.
It would also be helpful to say which release of CGAL you use, or if you use the master branch on github.

What was taking a long time was the elaboration of the delauny mesh without reading the excel file, I have solved it by adding all the points in a single batch as explained in the answer I posted.

I have done a lot of research and have managed to optimize the code with a very simple change.
To clarify, what it took was doing the triangulation, I'm not taking into account what it takes to read the file (which are only a few seconds) that is apart.
Solution:
In the function readExcelCSV I changed the first while loop to not add the points to the variable T while the file was being read, but to finish adding them to the variable points to later, once the loop was finished, insert all the points at once, the resulting code is the following.
std::string line;

int cont = 0;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::string value;
    std::vector<double> row;
        
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        std::getline(ss, value, ',');
        row.push_back(std::stod(value));
    }
       
    points.push_back(Point(row[0], row[1]));
    Coord_type value2 = row[2];
    values.insert(std::make_pair(points[cont], value2));
    cont++;
}
T.insert(points.begin(),points.end());

This improved the time it took to process the triangles from 18 seconds to >1 second.
I am using CGAL 6.0
I found the answer in the comment in the following link: CGAL Triangulation: Very slow point insertion
